# SQL query working in raw sql but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that works perfectly fine in phpmyadmin or a mysql terminal, it gives me what I want with over 250 results. But in php, it doesn't return anything. Just an empty set.

I have many other mysql queries that work perfectly fine, and some of them have even more rows so I don't think that's the issue...

The query:

```
SELECT `Participations_Reponses`.`reponseOK` 
FROM `Participations_Reponses`, `Questions`, `Concours_Questions`, `Participations` 
WHERE `Concours_Questions`.`idQuestion`=`Questions`.`idQuestion` 
AND `Participations_Reponses`.`numQuestion`=`Concours_Questions`.`numQuestion` 
AND `Participations`.`idConcours`=`Concours_Questions`.`idConcours` 
AND `Participations`.`idUtilisateur` = 'Pierre-Louis Legrand' 
AND `Questions`.`categorie` = 'Musique' 
GROUP BY `Questions`.`idQuestion`;
```

PHP :

```
$ret = YK_DB::requete($requete, array(YK_Connexion::IdentifiantMembreEnCours(), $pIdCategorie), true);
log_message("size of ret = " . sizeof($ret));
```

The logs says size of ret = 0 and the set is indeed empty. While, again, the exact same query works alright in the mysql terminal.

If needed, the requete() method is :

```
/**
 * Execute une requete
 *
 * @param string $pRequete    Requete MySQL
 * @param array  $pParametres Paramètres de requete
 *
 * @return array tableau associatif résultat
 */
static public function requete($pRequete = '', $pParametres = null, $debug = false) {
    // Définition globale de l'objet de connexion à la base
    if (!isset($GLOBALS['dbh_pdo'])) {
        global $SG_Config;
        $db_host = $SG_Config['MySQL_host'];
        $db_name = $SG_Config['MySQL_db'];
        $db_login = $SG_Config['MySQL_login'];
        $db_password = $SG_Config['MySQL_password'];

        $GLOBALS['dbh_pdo'] = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $db_login, $db_password);
    }
    //echo $pRequete;
    if (!is_null($pParametres)) {
        // S'il y a des paramètres à la requète
        $sth = $GLOBALS['dbh_pdo'] -> prepare($pRequete, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        if (gettype($pParametres) !== 'array') {
            $pParametres = array($pParametres);
        }
        $sth -> execute($pParametres);
        if ($debug) {
            echo YK_DB::show($pRequete, $pParametres);
        }
        return $sth -> fetchAll();
    } else {
        // Il n'y a pas de paramètre à la requète
        $result = $GLOBALS['dbh_pdo'] -> query($pRequete);
        $tab = array();
        if ($result !== false) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $tab[] = $row;
            }
            $result -> closeCursor();
        }
        return $tab;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know what is going on here. That's a ton of code there to wrap around PDO for reasons that aren't clear, plus the query in PHP isn't shown, it's buried inside a function you don't describe. What is `YK_Connexion::IdentifiantMembreEnCours()`?

Comment: What [errors](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) does PDO report?

Comment: It just fetches the id of the logged in user. It returns a string.

Comment: I don't know, there aren't any PDO error displayed anywhere... Not in the apache's logs or on screen at least

Comment: It does not look like you are checking for OR showing any PDO errors if and when they appear. If you want to wrap a perfectly good API (PDO) then at least you should make sure you do a proper job of it. You dont check for errors after a `prepare` or the `execute`

Comment: Okay so apparently, it's the GROUP BY which doesn't work. If I get rid of it, the request works in php too. I do need to use that group by tho.

Comment: @Kishlin, have a look at the errors _link_ I included in my comment.

Comment: @Chris Oh my bad, I did not see it yesterday. I tried using it, both after the prepare and execute, but it gives nothing ( "Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )" )

Comment: @Chris Actually I got it to work yesterday, I realised that removing the group by part made my sql query work even in php (altho it didn't return what I wanted) so I just reviewed my sql query so I don't need the group by and victory. Thanks for your help. :)